# Proxy config GUI vs. setting $http_proxy in /etc/environment?

Tags: gui, proxy, environment-variables

Ubuntu has a graphical interface to set proxy settings (see image, and [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-proxy.html)), inside Network Settings. Here I can set a manual proxy, ,with IP, port and user/password, or I can set auto config (PAC). Where is the config file that is affected by the settings here? Is this changing the environment variables `http_proxy`, etc.? What happens if I set `export http_proxy` in my `.bashrc`, or `/etc/environment`, how does this conflict with the GUI setting?

[image]

Comment: There GUI writes to /etc/environment and to /etc/apt/apt.conf. As for your bashrc, it won't affect GUI programs usually, but will be loaded last by your shell and will take priority in the terminal

Comment: @muru I just changed the GUI setting and the `/etc/environment` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` files show no changes (actually, I don't have an `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file.

Comment: Did you apply system-wide?

Comment: @muru Nope. If I don't apply system wide, where it writes?

Comment: Only in the gsettings database